# target= _blank on link inside email cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to add a `target=_blank` to this link that is sent by email. I have read the documentation on `html helper` and tried many things but I can still not figure it out. The link is sent from the controller.

```
$message .= '<a href ='.'http://xxxxx.com/pages/validate_access/$usercode:'.$hash.'/uxg:'.$passw.'>'.$labelsEmail.'</a><br/><br/>';
```

There is no link like this that is found on the documentation or anywhere on the web apparently. I have not been able to insert `target="_blank"` anywhere on this line with success. Does anybody have an idea how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you send HTML email or plain text?!

Comment: it's sent as "both".

Comment: $this->Email->sendAs = 'both';

Answer (score 0):

Use following syntax.

```
$message .= $this->Html->link($labelsEmail, 
'http://xxxxx.com/pages/validate_access/$usercode:'.$hash.'/uxg:'.$passw.', 
array('target' => '_blank'));
```

I think it will solve your problem.